# When to use chisquare or a simple teste for proportion

Tags: python, math, statistics, data-science, statsmodels

I tested a function to a proportion test and in it notes it was saying that the p_value that it returns is equal to the p_value that a chisquare returns, but i tested it and it didnt work.
I also compared the chisquare p_value with the p_value returned by the proportion test made by hand, and its equal
So my question is why the funcitons show different p_values? and when do i use the proportion test and the chisquare since the formula returns the same p_value?[function_note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSakN.png)

[fuctions_comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylpfs.png)

[formula_p_value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2GMZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

The relevant difference between proportions_ztest and proportions_chisquare is that the z-test uses by default a different variance assumption.

By default, the z-test uses the observed proportion of successes to compute the variance of the test statistic. The chisquare test is computed using the variance under the null hypothesis.

(The former corresponds to Wald tests, the latter corresponds to score tests.)

`proportions_ztest` has an option `prop_var` to set the proportion that is used to compute the variance. We can set it to the null value, 0.5 in this case.

Then, z-test and chisquare test produce the same p-value

```
import statsmodels.stats.proportion as prop
prop.proportions_chisquare(17, 50, value=0.5)
(5.12, 0.023651616655356, (array([[17., 33.]]), array([[25., 25.]])))

prop.proportions_ztest(17., 50, value=0.5, prop_var=0.5)
(-2.2627416997969516, 0.023651616655356)
```

The following shows that default `prop_var` is the observed proportion:

```
prop.proportions_ztest(17., 50, value=0.5)
(-2.3883257361061285, 0.01692533300395737)
prop.proportions_ztest(17., 50, value=0.5, prop_var=17 / 50)
(-2.3883257361061285, 0.01692533300395737)
```

Aside:

The default prop_var in proportions_ztest was not a good choice, because score tests for proportions have in general better properties than Wald test.

However, the default in proportion_ztest makes it equivalent to a standard z-test (without correcting degrees of freedom for a separate parameter)

```
from statsmodels.stats.weightstats import ztest

x = np.repeat([1, 0], [17, 33])
ztest(x, value=0.5, ddof=0)
(-2.3883257361061285, 0.01692533300395737)
```